# Increase products price by 10%

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

I am having problems increasing the prices of my hp products by 10%.

Here is what I've tried -->>

```
UPDATE products SET price = price*1.1;
from products 
where prod_name  like 'HP%'
```

Here is a picture of the products table:

[image]

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your query:

```
UPDATE products SET price = price*1.1;
from products 
where prod_name  like 'HP%'
```

It has one issue with the semicolon in the second row.  Also, it is not standard SQL (although this will work in some databases).  The standard way of expressing this is:

```
update products
    set price = price * 1.1
    where prod_name like 'HP%';
```

The `from` clause is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 3):

This is an `UPDATE`, not a `SELECT`, so the `FROM` clause is incorrect.  Also, the semicolon should go at the end of the last line.

```
UPDATE products SET price = price*1.1;  <==  Remove the semicolon
from products  <== remove this line
where prod_name  like 'HP%'  <== add a semicolon at the end of this line
```

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE products SET price = price*1.1
where prod_name  like 'HP%';
```

Comment: Is it OK to have the semicolon next to 1.1?

Comment: Oh, i missed that.  No, the semicolon should be revmoved from the first line and added to the end of the second line.  I'll edit my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Correct query would be like this:

```
update products set price = price * 1.1
where prod_name like 'HP%' ;
```

Don't know why you have highlighted Toshiba ? Do you want this to update ?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Products 
SET price = price+ price*0.1
WHERE prod_name LIKE 'HP%' ;
```